# Where am I going wrong when upgrading my react native version from 0.68.5 to 0.71.2?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

we use Nx Monorepo and our former mono repo and project versions and files are listed below;
**0.68.5**

```
{
  ...,
  "dependencies": {
    ...,
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.14.1",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "0.5.5",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "5.9.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "12.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "12.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "12.8.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^9.0.2",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.9.7",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "5.10.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "5.8.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "5.12.4",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.4.0",
    "@sentry/nextjs": "^7.38.0",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^4.6.1",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.24.4",
    "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.24.4",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "appcenter": "4.4.3",
    "appcenter-crashes": "4.0.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "axios": "0.24.0",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.18.2",
    "chart.js": "^4.2.1",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.2.0",
    "clean-css": "^5.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "css-loader": "^4.2.1",
    "cuid": "^2.1.8",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "eases": "^1.0.8",
    "embla-carousel-autoplay": "^6.0.2",
    "embla-carousel-react": "^6.0.2",
    "formik": "^2.2.6",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "i18n-js": "^3.8.0",
    "i18next": "^19.8.2",
    "i18next-chained-backend": "^3.0.2",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.4.1",
    "i18next-localstorage-backend": "^3.1.3",
    "iban": "^0.0.14",
    "immer": "^7.0.9",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.12.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.23",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "lottie-ios": "3.2.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.0.1",
    "metro-config": "0.71.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "2.15.2",
    "next": "12.1.5",
    "next-google-fonts": "^1.2.1",
    "next-i18next": "^11.0.0",
    "next-pwa": "5.5.4",
    "next-translate": "^1.4.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "object-to-formdata": "^4.4.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.20",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "rc-time-picker": "^3.7.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.2.4",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.8",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-i18next": "^11.7.3",
    "react-image-magnify": "^2.7.4",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native": "0.68.5",
    "react-native-android-location-enabler": "1.2.2",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "3.1.1",
    "react-native-code-push": "7.0.1",
    "react-native-config": "1.4.5",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "8.0.1",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "2.4.3",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.4",
    "react-native-fast-image": "8.3.4",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "7.3.3",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.8.0",
    "react-native-global-props": "1.1.5",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.8.4",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-localize": "1.4.3",
    "react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
    "react-native-modal": "11.5.6",
    "react-native-onesignal": "4.3.11",
    "react-native-otp-verify": "1.0.4",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "1.13.1",
    "react-native-restart": "0.0.24",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.8",
    "react-native-screens": "2.13.0",
    "react-native-set-soft-input-mode": "1.1.0",
    "react-native-signature-canvas": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "3.2.7",
    "react-native-swiper": "1.6.0-rc.3",
    "react-native-text-input-mask": "^3.1.4",
    "react-native-toast-message": "2.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "7.1.0",
    "react-native-version-check": "^3.4.7",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.1",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/helper-call-delegate": "^7.12.13",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.17.12",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.17.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.12.13",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.18.3",
    "@nrwl/cli": "^14.2.4",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "14.2.4",
    "@nrwl/detox": "14.2.4",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "14.2.4",
    "@nrwl/jest": "14.2.4",
    "@nrwl/linter": "14.2.4",
    "@nrwl/next": "14.2.4",
    "@nrwl/nx-cloud": "14.0.8",
    "@nrwl/react": "14.2.4",
    "@nrwl/react-native": "14.2.4",
    "@nrwl/storybook": "^14.2.4",
    "@nrwl/tao": "^14.2.4",
    "@nrwl/web": "14.2.4",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "14.2.4",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "7.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "7.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "7.0.1",
    "@react-theming/storybook-addon": "^1.1.7",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.0.17",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.0.17",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.0.17",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "~6.5.4",
    "@storybook/core-server": "~6.5.4",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "~6.5.4",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.0.17",
    "@storybook/testing-react": "^1.3.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^8.0.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "4.0.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "7.0.2",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "9.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "16.11.7",
    "@types/react": "17.0.30",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.9",
    "@types/react-native": "0.67.8",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.3.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.24.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.24.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "27.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "chromatic": "^6.7.3",
    "cra-bundle-analyzer": "^0.1.0",
    "cypress": "^9.1.0",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.8",
    "detox": "19.7.1",
    "eslint": "8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.5",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-mdx": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^5.0.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.0",
    "jest": "27.5.1",
    "jest-circus": "27.2.3",
    "jest-react-native": "18.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^13.0.3",
    "mdx-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "metro": "0.71.0",
    "metro-babel-register": "0.70.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.71.0",
    "metro-resolver": "0.71.0",
    "msw": "^0.44.2",
    "msw-storybook-addon": "^1.6.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "nx": "14.2.4",
    "prettier": "2.6.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.0",
    "react-is": "^16.13.1",
    "react-native-flipper": "0.137.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "1.0.0",
    "react-native-version": "^4.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
    "redux-flipper": "2.0.1",
    "storybook-addon-material-ui5": "^1.0.0",
    "storybook-addon-next-router": "3.1.1",
    "ts-jest": "27.1.4",
    "ts-node": "~10.8.0",
    "typescript": "4.7.3",
    "url-loader": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.4.1"
}
```

project package.json:

```
{
  ...,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "*",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "*",
    ...,
  }
}
```

podfile:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/@nrwl/react-native/nx_post_install'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'myApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  #use_frameworks!
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => true
  )
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../../../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleTagManager'

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    nx_post_install(installer)
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
              config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 3.0', '< 4.0'
end
```

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import <Firebase.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RNBootSplash.h"
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <CodePush/CodePush.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <AppCenterReactNative.h>
#import <AppCenterReactNativeCrashes.h>

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
 return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                  continueUserActivity:userActivity
                    restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}

static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif
[FIRApp configure];

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"main"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBackgroundColor];
  } else {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  }

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  [RNBootSplash initWithStoryboard:@"BootSplash" rootView:rootView];
    [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  [AppCenterReactNative register];
  [AppCenterReactNativeCrashes registerWithAutomaticProcessing];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"apps/myApp/src/main"];

#else
  return [CodePush bundleURL];
#endif
}

@end
```

main.m:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
  }
}
```

**MY NEW FILES AFTER UPGRADE 0.71.2:**

Monorepo package.json:

```
{
  ...,
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/react": "11.10.5",
    "@emotion/server": "11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.10.5",
    "@formatjs/intl-getcanonicallocales": "^2.0.5",
    "@formatjs/intl-locale": "^3.0.11",
    "@formatjs/intl-pluralrules": "^5.1.8",
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "2.1.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.112",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.0",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.11",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "0.5.5",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "5.9.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "12.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "12.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "12.8.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^9.0.2",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.9.7",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "5.10.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "5.8.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "5.12.4",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.9.0",
    "@sentry/nextjs": "^7.38.0",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^4.6.1",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.24.4",
    "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.24.4",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "appcenter": "4.4.5",
    "appcenter-crashes": "4.4.5",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.13",
    "axios": "0.24.0",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.18.2",
    "chart.js": "^4.2.1",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.2.0",
    "clean-css": "^5.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.4.0",
    "cuid": "^2.1.8",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "eases": "^1.0.8",
    "embla-carousel-autoplay": "^6.0.2",
    "embla-carousel-react": "^6.0.2",
    "formik": "^2.2.6",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "i18n-js": "^3.8.0",
    "i18next": "^19.8.2",
    "i18next-chained-backend": "^3.0.2",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.4.1",
    "i18next-localstorage-backend": "^3.1.3",
    "iban": "^0.0.14",
    "immer": "^7.0.9",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.12.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.23",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "lottie-ios": "3.2.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.0.1",
    "metro-config": "0.74.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "2.15.2",
    "next": "13.1.1",
    "next-google-fonts": "^1.2.1",
    "next-i18next": "^11.0.0",
    "next-pwa": "5.5.4",
    "next-translate": "^1.4.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "object-to-formdata": "^4.4.2",
    "postcss": "8.4.19",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "rc-time-picker": "^3.7.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.2.4",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.8",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-i18next": "^11.7.3",
    "react-image-magnify": "^2.7.4",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native": "0.71.2",
    "react-native-android-location-enabler": "1.2.2",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "3.1.1",
    "react-native-code-push": "7.0.1",
    "react-native-config": "1.5.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "8.0.1",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "2.4.3",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.4",
    "react-native-fast-image": "8.3.4",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "7.3.3",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.8.0",
    "react-native-global-props": "1.1.5",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.8.4",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-localize": "1.4.3",
    "react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
    "react-native-modal": "11.5.6",
    "react-native-onesignal": "4.3.11",
    "react-native-otp-verify": "1.0.4",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "1.13.1",
    "react-native-restart": "0.0.24",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.8",
    "react-native-screens": "2.13.0",
    "react-native-set-soft-input-mode": "1.1.0",
    "react-native-signature-canvas": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "13.8.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "3.2.7",
    "react-native-swiper": "1.6.0-rc.3",
    "react-native-text-input-mask": "^3.1.4",
    "react-native-toast-message": "2.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "7.1.0",
    "react-native-version-check": "^3.4.7",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.1",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
    "react-redux": "8.0.5",
    "react-router": "^6.4.1",
    "react-rte": "^0.16.5",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.27.10",
    "react-snowfall": "^1.0.2",
    "react-table": "7.7.0",
    "react-table-plugins": "^1.3.2",
    "react-toastify": "^8.2.0",
    "react-toasts": "^3.0.6",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^5.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-form": "^8.3.6",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-persist-transform-filter": "^0.0.20",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "0.13.7",
    "rn-placeholder": "3.0.3",
    "save-dev": "^0.0.1-security",
    "shelljs": "0.8.5",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "tss-react": "^4.5.2",
    "websocket": "^1.0.34",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "yarn": "^1.22.18",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/helper-call-delegate": "^7.12.13",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.17.12",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.17.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.12.13",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.20.13",
    "@nrwl/cli": "15.7.2",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "15.7.2",
    "@nrwl/detox": "15.7.2",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "15.7.2",
    "@nrwl/jest": "15.7.2",
    "@nrwl/js": "15.7.2",
    "@nrwl/linter": "15.7.2",
    "@nrwl/next": "15.7.2",
    "@nrwl/nx-cloud": "15.1.1",
    "@nrwl/react": "15.7.2",
    "@nrwl/react-native": "15.7.2",
    "@nrwl/storybook": "15.7.2",
    "@nrwl/tao": "15.7.2",
    "@nrwl/web": "15.7.2",
    "@nrwl/webpack": "15.7.2",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "15.7.2",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.7",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "10.1.3",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "10.1.3",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "10.1.1",
    "@react-theming/storybook-addon": "^1.1.7",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.0.17",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "6.5.16",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.0.17",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "6.5.16",
    "@storybook/core-server": "6.5.16",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "6.5.16",
    "@storybook/react": "6.5.16",
    "@storybook/testing-react": "^1.3.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.1.2",
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^8.0.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "5.4.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "7.0.2",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "11.5.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "28.1.8",
    "@types/node": "18.11.18",
    "@types/react": "18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.9",
    "@types/react-native": "0.71.2",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.3.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.54.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.54.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "28.1.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "chromatic": "^6.7.3",
    "cra-bundle-analyzer": "^0.1.0",
    "cypress": "^9.1.0",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.8",
    "detox": "20.1.1",
    "eslint": "8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-mdx": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.31.11",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^5.0.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.0",
    "jest": "28.1.3",
    "jest-circus": "28.1.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "28.1.3",
    "jest-jasmine2": "28.1.1",
    "jest-react-native": "18.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^13.0.3",
    "mdx-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "metro": "0.74.1",
    "metro-babel-register": "0.74.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.74.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-transformer": "0.74.1",
    "metro-resolver": "0.74.1",
    "msw": "^0.44.2",
    "msw-storybook-addon": "^1.6.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "nx": "15.7.2",
    "prettier": "2.6.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.0",
    "react-is": "18.2.0",
    "react-native-flipper": "0.137.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "1.0.0",
    "react-native-version": "^4.0.0",
    "react-refresh": "^0.10.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "redux-flipper": "2.0.1",
    "storybook-addon-material-ui5": "^1.0.0",
    "storybook-addon-next-router": "3.1.1",
    "stylus": "^0.55.0",
    "stylus-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "28.0.8",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "4.8.4",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.4.1"
}
```

project package.json:

```
{...,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "*",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "*",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "*",
    "react": "*",
    "react-native": "*",
    "react-native-config": "*",
    "react-native-svg": "*",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "*",
    "prop-types": "*",
    "metro-config": "*",
    "react-redux": "*",
    ...
  }
}
```

metro.config.js:

```
const { withNxMetro } = require('@nrwl/react-native')
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config')
const exclusionList = require('metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList')

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig()
  return withNxMetro(
    {
      transformer: {
        getTransformOptions: async () => ({
          transform: {
            experimentalImportSupport: false,
            inlineRequires: true
          }
        }),
        babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer')
      },
      resolver: {
        assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
        sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
        blockList: exclusionList([/^(?!.*node_modules).*\/dist\/.*/])
      }
    },
    {
      // Change this to true to see debugging info.
      // Useful if you have issues resolving modules
      debug: false,
      // all the file extensions used for imports other than 'ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json'
      extensions: [],
      // the project root to start the metro server
      projectRoot: __dirname,
      // Specify folders to watch, in addition to Nx defaults (workspace libraries and node_modules)
      watchFolders: []
    }
  )
})()
```

Podfile:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/@nrwl/react-native/nx_post_install'

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'myApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  # target 'myApp' do
  #   inherit! :complete
  #   # Pods for testing
  # end

  # Pods for myApp
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleTagManager'

 

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    nx_post_install(installer)
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
              config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 3.0', '< 4.0'
end
```

AppDelegate.mm:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Firebase.h> 
#import "RNBootSplash.h"
// #import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
// #import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <CodePush/CodePush.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <AppCenterReactNative.h>
#import <AppCenterReactNativeCrashes.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
 return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                  continueUserActivity:userActivity
                    restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = @"myApp";
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];

#else
  return [CodePush bundleURL];
#endif
}

- (BOOL)concurrentRootEnabled
{
  return true;
}

@end
```

main.m:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
  }
}
```

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <RCTAppDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : RCTAppDelegate

@end
```

**ERROR**

> success Successfully launched the app on the simulator
> Error: Cannot resolve ./index
> at /Users/ismail/Desktop/developement/work/my-client/node_modules/@nrwl/react-native/plugins/metro-resolver.js:31:15
> at Object.resolve (/Users/ismail/Desktop/developement/work/my-client/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-resolver/src/resolve.js:27:12)
> ...

I have migrated my Nx Mono repo to latest and run migrations. Then I made changes above acording to documentation and still not able to run my app.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is old, but it may help others in the future:

I recommend using this helper whenever you make updates in React Native versions:
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper

It shows all the necessary changes, but be sure to keep any specific previous changes from already installed libraries.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35040734)

Comment: It's impossible because the link directs to a project where you can input your current React Native version and the target version. It will then display the differences and important features implemented between the two versions.

Thus, one can use it to determine what will be useful for each individual.